# How do i share the same context with mutiple different processes?

Tags: c#, .net, service, command-line-interface, ipc

After creating a Server-Client based application, i wrote a simple CLI application for managing the server-instance with actions like startListening, stopListening, getLogs, listClients and so on. Now it would be usefull for the user to open multiple terminals for observing and managing the server at the same time.

This brought me to the question on how to archieve this, since by now the server-instance is bound to the console-application process.

**How do i share the server-instance to mutiple different processes?**

Things i thought of were: making the server-instance a service with simple interface or implement inter-process communication, but i don't know if it would overshoot the mark.

Comment: What technique have you used to connect Client&Server? I have a hard time thinking of a technique one can choose that wouldn't get what you want more or less automatically.

Comment: Its an async TCP Server to which multiple clients can connect to. The clients do not matter in this case because they connect over tcp. The Admin on the other hand uses my cli app (on same machine as the server) to manage it. @Ralf

Comment: And the cli app does not use also the TCP interface? What does the cli use? That one is also a client to me.

Comment: The cli app is basically the server and thats what im trying to change. I try to make the server a standalone application, but since the cli app is always on the same machine, id rather not connect over tcp or anything like that. So im looking for some other type of intercommunication @Ralf

Comment: I would still use something like tcp or http(s) that gives you the most options to evolve the thing from there. But if you want to have something purely local then "named pipes"  as ipc mechanism between your cli app and the server process might be something to look at. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication

Comment: This seems like exaclty what i'm looking for. Thank you!